# The x label of a box plot is shifted

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I use the code below to box plot several columns in `dataframe`.

```
df = df[["Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4", "Col5", "Col6", "Col7"]]

df.plot.box()
plt.xticks(list(range(len(df.columns))), df.columns, rotation='vertical')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

The graph is as follow.

[image]

But, as you can see, the x label is shifted one step to the left leaving the rightest one without any label

I am wondering what would be the solution to this. Thank you.

Comment: `range(1, len(df.columns)+1)`

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest. thanks, it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason the ticks are off is because `range(len(df.columns))`starts at zero while box plots default to `range(1,N+1)` in the documentation.

As pointed out by IOBE, you can add 1 to the start of `range` and increase the upper limit to conserve the same number of columns to show.  You could also specify the ticks directly when plotting by using the `positions` [kwarg](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot.html).

```
df = df[["Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4", "Col5", "Col6", "Col7"]]

df.plot.box()
plt.xticks(list(range(1,len(df.columns)+1)), df.columns, rotation='vertical')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```